# Jenkins Windows Slave not using correct credentials for git

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a Jenkins master (ubuntu) that uses a Windows slave to build a UWP app. When it is trying to run a git fetch I get the following error:-

```
git fetch --tags --progress git@gitlab.com:user/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
23:24:08 ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
23:24:08 hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@gitlab.com:user/repo.git
23:24:08    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:803)
23:24:08    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1063)
23:24:08    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1094)
23:24:08    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
23:24:08    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1276)
23:24:08    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:560)
23:24:08    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
23:24:08    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:485)
23:24:08    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
23:24:08    at hudson.matrix.MatrixRun.run(MatrixRun.java:153)
23:24:08    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
23:24:08    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
23:24:08 Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress git@gitlab.com:user/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
23:24:08 stdout: 
23:24:08 stderr: jenkins_user@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
23:24:08 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

It seems to be using the wrong email address to fetch the repository. It should be jenkins_user@domain.com not @gitlab.com but even if I do a `git config --global user.email jenkins_user@domain.com` it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not related to `user.email` config in your local repository.

When jenkins slave is installed as a Windows service (to ensure the agent runs even if nobody login on the machine), the user that runs jenkins binary is the Local System Account. You have to create a SSH public/private key pair and put it under the right folder on your machine:

```
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.ssh
```

You will also need to copy a proper `known_hosts` file, to ensure the first `git pull` will work without asking to type `yes` on the command line (impossible from a jenkins job).

**Warning :** Most of the time, when Windows Update perform a system upgrade, this folder is cleaned and you lost your key. You will have to save the files somewhere else to ensure you can restore them after an upgrade.

See [this post](https://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/how-to-authorize-local-system-account-for-openssh/) for additional information, or search for "ssh key local system account" on your preferred search engine.

Comment: The service runs under a different local account, not the system account.

Comment: Then, you have to put ssh keypair under .ssh folder in this account's user profile